# Limit of equations.

Tags: calculus, limits

$a_{n}+b_{n}+c_{n}=2n-1 $

$a_{n}b_{n}+b_{n}c_{n}+a_{n}c_{n}=2n+1 $

$a_{n}b_{n}c_{n}=-1 $

$a_{n}<b_{n}<c_{n}.$

Find $\lim\limits_{n\to \infty}na_{n}.$

ATTEMPT:

From $ (2). $

$b_{n}+c_{n}=\frac{2n+1-b_{n}c_{n}}{a_{n}}.$

From $ (3).$

$b_{n}c_{n}=\frac{-1}{a_{n}}.$

Plugging in $(1).$ we get:

${a_{n}}^3-(2n-1){a_{n}}^2+(2n+1)a_{n}+1=0.$

But i am not able to solve further?

I wonder what's the use of inequality here ?

Answer (score 6):

From the assumption we have $a_{n}<0<b_{n}<c_{n}$. Hence $b_{n}c_{n}%
=2n+1-a_{n}\left(  b_{n}+c_{n}\right)  >2n+1.$ Hence we have
$$
a_{n}=-\frac{1}{b_{n}c_{n}}\rightarrow0\text{ and }na_{n}^{2}\rightarrow0.
$$
Now from $a_{n}^{3}-\left(  2n-1\right)  a_{n}^{2}+\left(  2n+1\right)
a_{n}+1=0$ we get $0-0+2\lim na_{n}+1=0$ so $\lim na_{n}=-\frac{1}{2}.$